# Is there any automated way to convert the CSV files in Azure Blob Storage to Excel tables?

Tags: excel, azure, csv, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

I am trying to export the content of csv files stored in Azure Blob Storage to Excel tables in an automated way. I did some research and found in few blog articles that Azure Logic App could be used for the conversion. I tried to implement something similar but couldn't succeed.

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: First question, do you really need to 'convert'?  Excel handles CSV data quite well already.

Comment: I second @Johns-305 comment.  A better way to ask Johns' question again would be: *What are you trying to do that using Excel with the existing CSVs would not allow?*

Comment: @Johns-305 Yes, i need to have Excel output.

Comment: @gravity The output should be in Excel format and the process of conversion should be automated.

Comment: Ok, then the question becomes, exactly which Excel format?  .xml, .xls, .xlsx, .csv (which Excel supports natively )

Comment: @Johns-305 Excel output should be need in .xlsx format.

Comment: Should have asked before, how many rows are in these files and how many files per day/hour?

Comment: @Johns-305 There are around 250k rows in the file.

Comment: I would test the below Answer very carefully.  250K is a lot of OneDrive operations and there could be unintended side-effects, like 250K previous versions depending on how the connection is handled in the For Each.

Comment: To be clear, I think you should quadruple check that you even need to convert.  To the user experience in Excel, there's practically no difference between .xlsx and .csv.

Comment: Have you considered to call Azure Databricks notebook where Python script will do the whole job for you?

Comment: @KamilNowinski Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please describe it in more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to go this route [I built this the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56605095/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-using-template-via-azure-logic-app), not that I think this is the best way to handle this but it is a way. You can build further upon this example, change the input to storage blob and the output to excel. I am just pasting the extra step where I set the output to Excel add a row into a table. **Keep in mind you will need to purge the header and the last row** So you need to at least fix that part.

[image: Excel table]

Find the entire flow in the other question I linked to earlier. The difference is just that I now look in a storage blob, compose the output and in the end, I write to the Excel table
[image: Flow]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As i am quite new to logic app, i couldn't solve my issue with the above provided information. Could you please provide the detailed step-wise solution? That would be very much appreciated.