# Convert CSV to JSON using Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, csv, azure-logic-apps, csvtojson

I'm using an Azure Logic App to get Blob contents from my storage account. The Blob-file is in .CSV format. I want to convert the CSV file into JSON.

I'm aware of the third party connectors like Plumsail documents, but they are paid. Is there a no-cost solution to this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split the content of the csv file using the `split` method, then store it in an array through traversal, and then append it into a `Json` string.

For example, the content of the csv file is

```
test1,test2,test3
testx,testy,testz
```

You need to split each line first, and then split each line with `,`.

Note that `\r\n` is not easy to type in logic app, you can write it in Notepad first, and then paste it into ʻExpression`：

```
split(body('Get_blob_content_using_path'),'
')
```

[image]

You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56605095/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-using-template-via-azure-logic-app). Although it is very cumbersome, it still has reference significance.

=============update==================

The complete workflow is as follows：

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note:

In `for each`, you need to enable `Concurrency Control` and set its value to 1, otherwise it will execute in parallel and cause the append operation to be out of order.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you response @frank!
What next after the For_each_2 step?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have updated my answer, I hope it can be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Azure function using the PowerShell runtime and then use the PowerShell cmdlets `ConvertFrom-CSV` and `ConvertTo-Json`. The function can be called from the Logic App.

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

$Output = $Request.Body | ConvertFrom-CSV | ConvertTo-Json

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $Output
})
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-powershell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-powershell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.2